# Can't send email with smtp

Tags: python, python-2.7, email

I want to know why this code can't send email.

```
import smtplib

content = 'test'

mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login('surapon@gmail.com','222222')
mail.sendmail('surapon@gmail.com','youremail@gmail.com',content)
mail.quit
```

It shows:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8 support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 ho10sm6301275pbc.27 - gsmtp')
```

Later, it shows:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu87\n5.7.14 wdTx8uq_F_WXKXEVia5I3DTMdhzuJL967nviDbOqgBU9lHzjzIHX69az6PFAzff6lA2uGJ\n5.7.14 qCqwJzys1OcoqMzMNUx5o5ja_a3XHatcxE-jqsHjqWCwYR1WVUEmBfGvUIBzgm7iUyGOXq\n5.7.14 RdYOqEx5GLAe05yUhGq-z-JphFKH-x-aA0TwEc-hyEnecghY1ZLtMMsowPhFGa1XGPnNO3\n5.7.14 8XE4yhQctKtYySbTSiQqBUmmV4qE> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14 Learn more at\n5.7.14 support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 eu5sm6412101pac.37 - gsmtp')
```

Comment: it's show SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 ho10sm6301275pbc.27 - gsmtp')

Answer (score 2):

I created yagmail as a package to make it really simple to send emails.

Please try the following:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP('surapon@gmail.com', 'password')
yag.send('youremail@gmail.com', subject = 'hi', contents = content)
```

There are some useful other tricks you can do with the package, such as never having to enter the password again (while still being secure), and it makes it extremely easy to send attachments.

Install with either

```
pip install yagmail  # python 2
pip3 install yagmail # python 3
```

and for more information please have a look at [github](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail).

Comment: Hi Pascal, thanks for your package, I've tried above, however get the message: AttributeError: module 'yagmail' has no attribute 'Connect'. Also, if I make the following change to the script, by adding : yag = yagmail.SMTP("verxxx@gmail.com", "XXXX!"), I get the following: "smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted." The credentials however are correct, as I've managed to send e-mails using the same credentials with a different script.

Comment: shout out to you sir! I just tried your packages, it is flawless and elegant!

Answer (score 0):

`Due to security issues gmail blocks accessing mail via code or program`

But still you can use gmail to send mail  via code if you do the following things

What i have done in code :

1.Added a error object to get the error message

```
import smtplib    

try:
    content = 'test'

    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('surapon@gmail.com','222222')
    mail.sendmail('surapon@gmail.com','youremail@gmail.com',content)
    mail.quit
    print "Successfully sent email"
except smtplib.SMTPException,error:
    print str(error)
    print "Error: unable to send email"
```

If u ran this code u would see a error message like this stating  that google is not allowing u to login via code

Things to change in gmail:

1.Login to gmail

2.Go to this link  https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

3.Click enable then retry the code

Hopes it help :)

But there are security threats if u enable it

Comment: Emphasis on step 2. This wont work without it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because google considers python SMTPLIB less secure.  The link in the error message leads you to the answer.

Within that link there is another link to allowing "less secure" apps to send mail.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

This allows you to specifically allow your application to send email.  They provide very little information on what constitutes the security issue.

The link they provide to give explicit access is
http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps  within the earlier link.

Answer (score -1):

I'll explain what you're trying to do. You're attempting to do an SMTP with the following credentials:
'smtp.gmail.com',587
Then you're attempting to login with your gmail creds. Totally wrong.
What you want to do is:

```
import smtplib

content = 'test'

me = 'surapon@gmail.com'
you = ['someOther@gmail.com']

mail = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')

msg['Subject'] = 'Hello'
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you[0]
#mail.ehlo()
#mail.starttls()
#mail.login('surapon@gmail.com','222222')
mail.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
mail.quit()
```

Comment: The above would not work until he has a local smtp server installed in his system.

Comment: With what you wrote you're attempting to log into gmail smtp and then mail yourself at gmail. Doesn't make sense. What you want to do is from 'localhost' <- This will either be your machine or a server dependent on where you're running your script from. This will create the mail and send to gmail.

Comment: ok now i can send gmail to gmail but i wonder if i want to send from gmail go to author mail  example surapon@gmail.com send to dark@synex.com

Comment: You're still going to send from that server regardless. It is still localhost. However, your 'To' and 'From' values can say anything

Answer (score -1):

Do not include the @gmail.com in your credentials. I used your code with my username (without @gmail.com) and password and was able to send a message.

```
import smtplib

content = 'test'

mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login('surapon','222222')
mail.sendmail('surapon@gmail.com','youremail@gmail.com',content)
mail.quit
```

Comment: Why did the question and each answer get a down vote?